# Can you run Windows 8 on a 800x480 small-screen device?

Tags: windows-8, resolution, touchscreen

I have installed Windows 8 Pro on a PC without problems.

However, when a MiMo 7" touchscreen is used instead of the main monitor, and  the desktop is running at a 800x480 resolution, the regular applications (Mail, News, etc) do not run and say that this resolution is not supported.

Is there a fix or workaround for this (other than using a higher-res touchscreen)?

Comment: What you want to do is not supported.  Any hacks anything that would allow this would be a hack which might work today but not tommorow.

Comment: According to http://blogs.msdn.com/b/b8/archive/2012/03/21/scaling-to-different-screens.aspx you need a minimum screen resolution of 1024x768. This was a deliberate choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Windows 8 minimum specifications for screen resolution is 1024x768.

From [Running the Consumer Preview: system recommendations](https://web.archive.org/web/20151030045256/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/b8/archive/2012/02/29/running-the-consumer-preview-system-recommendations.aspx):

> One new element to Windows 8 is the requirement that Metro style applications have a minimum of 1024x768 screen resolution

Answer (score 0):

Actually. It is possible to run Windows 8 on screens lower than 1024x768, however metro apps will not work. If you want to only use "Aero" based apps, then a lower-res screen will work fine. But if you want the metro apps, then you would need to connect to an external monitor.

There is no hack to bypass this anymore that I am aware of.